# Is a profile required when developing both an app and a Bluetooth 4.0 LE accessory?

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I am developing a Bluetooth 4.0 accessory and an app that interfaces with it.  Do I have to choose a Bluetooth profile for this device?  It seems like a profile is just a defined set of services / characteristics which enables all keyboards to talk to all mobile devices (for example).  If I am doing the work on both sides for a custom peripheral, is there any need to conform to a defined profile?

According to this document (http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3647), iOS only supports a limited set of profiles, but I am curious if those are for OS-level functions (like using a headset on a phone call for example), not custom app development.

Comment: Since BLE isn't suited for Audio, HeadSet & Phone Call won't be pass through BLE. So be careful and don't mix "classical Bluetooth" and Bluetooth Low Energy.

Comment: Are the profiles only used for classic bluetooth?